# Module to separate the links of menus by language?

Tags: 7, routes

A few days ago I found a module to separate the links of menus by language. Given a localized menu then you get the links separated by languages. Very useful I think.

But now I can't remember its name. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it's a sandbox project though: http://drupal.org/sandbox/TimBrandin/1835360